# nested radical simplification

Tags: trigonometry, nested-radicals

I'm stuck on this radical simplification  $$ (\sqrt{5}+1) \sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}$$
In my textbook this product is equal to the $tan(\frac{2\pi}{5})$ and the value is : $$ 4 \sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{5}} $$

I tried to do  some simplification and I stopped at this step
$$ \sqrt{5(10+2\sqrt{5})}+\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: Move the $\sqrt{5}+1$ factor inside the radical and see what you get.

Comment: when I  move $\sqrt{5}+1$ inside the radical I get the third formula. However, now it's work when I consider  $\sqrt{5}+1$ as $\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: What I meant is $\,\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^2\left(10+2\sqrt{5}\right)}\,$ which gives you the second formula.

Comment: what I did is the same.  $\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}$. So you can put your answer so that I can validate it. Thank you

Comment: It is perfectly fine, even encouraged, that you post a self-answer if you solved it.

Comment: your word 'move factor inside' gave me the idea, so it's your solution